# Please, help me install libboost1.40-all-dev

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install NXT-ROS and in order for me to do that, I need `libboost1.40-all-dev`

When I input the command `sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-dev-all` I get the following:

```
root@joel:~# sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost1.40-all-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listwget' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'libboost1.40-all-dev' has no installation candidate

root@joel:~#
```

BY the way, I have no clue what those last few lines are so just ignore them if they are not causing the problem, but if there is easy fix to this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a link to the installation instructions that you are following. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you trying to install NXT-ROS from source (as implied by your need for `-dev` packages) or from the `ros-latest` repository (as implied by your - broken - /etc/apt/sources.list.d entry)?

Comment: You have some files that have wrong names, probably as a result of some typos. In /etc/apt/sources.d/, you have one file called ros-latest.listwget and one called ros-latest.listsudo. These are wrong. It should be ros-latest.list. Make sure you have the latter and remove the others. The do an apt-get update and try to install again.

Answer (score 2):

[`libboost1.40-all-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost1.40-all-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) is a very old package that was only made available for Ubuntu 10.04. Up until the end of this month this package is still available, but only for the Server edition of Ubuntu 10.04.

If you want to stick with the package management, you better install the meta-package:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 this will get you `libboost1.54-all-dev` installed.

Otherwise, if you really need version 1.40, then you have to fetch it from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.40.0/) and install it manually. I could not find an install guide in the [Boost web site](http://www.boost.org).

Comment: Thanks, I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on Oracle VM VirtualBox and got it. The host OS is Ubuntu 12.04. Now my question is, how do I make the OS in Oracle VM VirtualBox to recognize my USB and my NXT Legos Intelligent Brick?